# Pyspark - How to get count of a particular element in an array without exploding?

Tags: arrays, pyspark, types

Input dataframe:

| Name | action |
| --- | --- |
| a | [walk,run,sit,walk,run,sit] |
| b | [walk,sit,run,walk,sleep,wait] |

Calculate action count of walk and run without exploding the array like below output dataframe.

| Name | action | walk_count | run_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | [walk,run,sit,walk,run,sit] | 2 | 2 |
| b | [walk,sit,run,walk,sleep,wait] | 2 | 0 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `higher order` **`filter`** function in pyspark.

- `size(filter(action,n -> n == 'walk'))` -> get the array each item then filter only the matching record then get the size of array

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('a',['walk','run','sit','walk','run','sit'])],['name','action'])
df.withColumn("walk_count", expr("""size(filter(action,n -> n == 'walk'))""")).\
withColumn("run_count", expr("""size(filter(action,n -> n == 'run'))""")).\
show(10,False)

#+----+--------------------------------+----------+---------+
#|name|action                          |walk_count|run_count|
#+----+--------------------------------+----------+---------+
#|a   |[walk, run, sit, walk, run, sit]|2         |2        |
#+----+--------------------------------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped to solve the issue, to count an array without exploding. However, due to large data volume(in billions), the processing is slow. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Its going to be relative...? how many workers/memory/partitions you have and how much time its taking now?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `aggregate` function as follows:

```
agg_cols = ['walk', 'run']

for col in agg_cols:
    df = df.withColumn(f'{col}_count', f.expr(f"aggregate(action, 0, (acc, x) -> if(x = '{col}', acc + 1, acc))"))

df.show(truncate=False)

+----+--------------------------------+----------+---------+
|name|action                          |walk_count|run_count|
+----+--------------------------------+----------+---------+
|a   |[walk, run, sit, walk, run, sit]|2         |2        |
+----+--------------------------------+----------+---------+
```